# How to get DBCursor->get(...) to recognize the memory I have allocated for key.data and data.data

Tags: c, berkeley-db

I am working on a C program to pull records whose data values match a certain pattern from a BerkeleyDB DBTree database. I create the database, open it, zero out a DBT for key and another for data, set the DBT flags to DB_DBT_USERMEM, malloc large buffers for data members of the DBTs, set the DBT ulen slot to the size of the allocated buffers, get a cursor, and come to this line

ret = cursor->get(cursor, &key, &data, DB_NEXT);

ret is always DB_BUFFER_SMALL, although the malloced buffers are 2056 characters and the size of key.data is 25 and data.data is 75.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I am assigning the malloced memory buffers to the DBT data member like this 'key.data = (char *)malloc(dataSize); key.ulen = dataSize;'

Comment: It sounds like you're doing it correctly.   The USERMEM flag is where most go wrong.  Can you post the exact code you're using to initialize key and data?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for asking the question. It led me to the solution, which was

```
/* Initialize key/data structures. */
memset(&key, 0, sizeof(key));
memset(&data, 0, sizeof(data));

key.flags = DB_DBT_USERMEM;
data.flags = DB_DBT_USERMEM;

key.data = (char *)malloc(dataSize);
key.ulen = dataSize;
data.data = (char *)malloc(dataSize);
data.ulen = dataSize;

memset(key.data, 0, sizeof(key.data));
memset(data.data, 0, sizeof(data.data));
```

instead of

```
/* Initialize key/data structures. */
memset(&key, 0, sizeof(key));
memset(&data, 0, sizeof(data));

key.flags = DB_DBT_USERMEM;
data.flags = DB_DBT_USERMEM;

key.data = (char *)malloc(dataSize);
key.ulen = dataSize;
data.data = (char *)malloc(dataSize);
data.ulen = dataSize;

memset(&(key.data), 0, sizeof(key.data));
memset(&(data.data), 0, sizeof(data.data));
```

I was passing a pointer to a char * pointer to memset, instead of passing the pointer itself. Your question caused me to question the init code.

Thanks

Comment: Great!  Since your description sounded correct, it had to be something specific about the implementation.